# Finding whole number solution to a multi variable nonlinear equation

Tags: number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, exponential-sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^z 10^n = 3^x*7^y$$

Given the equation above, how do I find solutions where $x,y,z$ are all whole numbers and $z\neq0$. Or if no such solutions exist how to prove it?
In other words I'm trying to find if there are numbers comprised only from 1s (1,11,111 etc) that can be perfectly factorised with only 3s and 7s.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @dietrich-burde how can I write complex functions like sums or such in other way? Sorry I'm new. I try to copy formula from desmos but it made a mess here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*. Powers of $7$ are never of the form $1111\cdots 11111$.

So we need a prime divisor $3$. But then the number of $1$'s must be divisible by $3$, so that $37$ is always a prime divisor of $111\cdots 111\cdots 111$.

Comment: Seems true for small numbers, but is there any way to prove it? Why power of 7 will never be 1's ? And why "37  is always a prime divisor of 111⋯111⋯111"? (in decimal)

Comment: The last digit of $7^y$ is $1$ if and only if $4\mid y$, but then the second last digit is $0$ and not $1$. Using elementary number theory theory you can prove everything more formally. This is what you have to do now, given these hints.